# sum of 3 sine waves, with uniformly distributed frequency and phase

Tags: probability

To my surprise, the sum of three sine waves of similar frequencies and random phase doesn't necessarily has its maximum at 3 which I simply assumed to be correct.*

This question arise from a electrical power network problem. To put it short, many sine wave sources with frequency centered at 16kHz and phase randomly distributed are connected to one single power line. We need to know to maximum voltage that can occur to this power line and how often does it occur to evaluate the effect of the sources on the power network.

To simply the problem, I started analyzing the maximum sum of 3 sources and find it already difficult for me to see the possibility distribution for the maximum sum.

Any help is appreciated!

*To verify this, you can run a simple test in Matlab. With appropriate time range and step width,  you will find max[sin(16*e3*t+pi*1/4)+sin(16.07*e3*t+pi*1/2)+sin(15.97*e3*t+pi*3/4)]=2.95 which is out of Matlab's floating point error range and thus indicates the possibility of the maximum sum to be smaller than 3.